# Using \ref in tikzpicture node while using externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, cross-referencing

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=extfig/]

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    a = b
    \label{equation}
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (input) {see equation \ref{equation}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The node inside `tikzpicture` shows `see equation ??`. How to make the reference work? (BTW: it works well without using the externalize lib.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The externalization process puts the pictures in a separate PDF file, which is then included as image. However annotations are usually lost, when
a PDF page is included.

There are only quite complicated workarounds, e.g., project [`pax`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax), which
uses a PDF library to extract the annotations from the PDF file to reinsert them later at TeX level.

Or reference can be put in a node and its coordinates relative to the bounding box remembered and then the link can be added later on top of the included image (via package `overpic` or again via `tikz`).

But I think, it might be much easier just to exclude the pictures with the references from the externalization. Section "50.4.3 Remaking Figures or Skipping Figures" from the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) shows some options to disable the export of a figure, e.g.:

```
\tikzset{external/export next=false}
\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
```

or

```
\tikzexternalexportnextfalse
\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
```

or

```
\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzexternalenable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know how I can exclude specific tikzpictures from the externalization process and externalize everything else?