# Cross references from TiKz figure to section or figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, cross-referencing

Is it possible to invoke `\ref` and `\pageref` to figures and sections from inside a tikz figure ?

I've searched quite a bit but did not found a straight forwar answer.

To be more specific, here is what I'd like to do if it's possible:

---

The idea would be to have a global chart representing a paradigm.

Quite a few nodes on that chart will have its own section in the paper: I'd like to insert a cross reference so the reader may look at the chart and click on the subject of his interest.

```
\begin{document}

\section{section 1}
    \label{sec:section1}

\section{section 2}

\secion{section 3}

%---------------------------------

\backmatter

\begin{tikzfigure}

    \node at (-2,0) {a subject (\ref{sec:section1})};

\end{tikzfigure}

\end{document}
```

For the record, if needed, a few details of my preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Thaks beforehand for any advice :-)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245411/using-ref-in-tikzpicture-node-while-using-externalize) it might be useful.

Comment: Did you try? (The answer is yes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, no tricks are needed, just use `\ref` and `\pageref` like any other place.

With the code below the `tikzpicture` looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\section{section 1}
 \label{sec:section1}
\chapter{Bar}
\section{section 2}
\label{sec:section2}

\backmatter

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [align=left] {
    section 1.1.: \ref{sec:section1} on page \pageref{sec:section1} \\
    section 2.1.: \ref{sec:section2} on page \pageref{sec:section2} 
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice ! It works really smooth, that's great ! Thanks :-)