# How to correct misplaced cross-reference boxes in a Tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, hyperref, cross-referencing, tikz-node

I am using a quite recent installation of TeXLive 2021. I have a document with a `Tikz` picture that contains `\ref{}` commands which refer to parts of the text. Compiling with pdfLaTeX can resolve the cross references. However the (default) red boxes that are supposed to appear over the cross references are misplaced. I have tried changing the `align` option for nodes in the `Tikz`, but this just moves the red box to somewhere else inappropriate. Any suggestions for how to remedy this are welcome.
A MWE follows:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% This is a simple template for a LaTeX document using the "article" class.
% See "book", "report", "letter" for other types of document.

\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)

%%% Examples of Article customizations
% These packages are optional, depending whether you want the features they provide.
% See the LaTeX Companion or other references for full information.

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.markings} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}



%%% END Article customizations

%%% The "real" document content comes below...

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
%\date{} % Activate to display a given date or no date (if empty),
         % otherwise the current date is printed 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First section} \label{s:S1}

\begin{definition} \label{def:synonyms}
Test defn.
\end{definition}

Your text goes here.

\section{Second section} \label{s:S2}

Why are the hyperref boxes in the tikzpicture below not located over the ref commands? \\
Changing the align option for nodes does not help. \\
\vspace{10pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
% Give us a centre to work around with node placement
\node[] (centre) at + (0,0) {};

\node[draw, text width=26mm, text centered,  minimum height=5mm,font=\normalsize,
    trapezium,
    trapezium left angle = 65,
    trapezium right angle = 115,
    trapezium stretches] (S1trap) {Intro:
(Defn~\ref{def:synonyms}, Sect. \ref{s:S1})};

\node[right=1cm of S1trap.east, draw, text centered, text width=32mm, align=center](S2box) {More stuff (Sect.~\ref{s:S2})};
\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Comment: What red boxes are you talking about? The code shows two nodes with some content in it and it seems to look as it should.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein the three red boxes are added by the inclusion of \usepackage{hyperref} in the preamble. The boxes are not positioned over each of the three \ref{} commands in the tikzpicture, which is not usual for these boxes.

Comment: Ok, but then it seems that I miss something, because there are no red boxes with the code copied to texmaker on my PC.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein I cannot comment on PC use, I am using TexWorks to edit/compile LaTeX on a mac. Red boxes for cross-references when the `hyperref` package is used is a standard feature. For an example, see this:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431957/cross-references-from-tikz-figure-to-section-or-figures

Comment: The reason was the PDF-viewer. With Acrobat I see the boxes, which are in fact not at the right place like shown in your comment above.

Comment: An alternative could be: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87026/wrong-place-for-hyperref-link-in-scaled-tikz-picture

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein I followed that link - a good catch that my searching missed, maybe because the issue is so old. The problem seems to be (compiling with pdfLaTeX) due to the scaling, which is removed by:
\scalebox{0.7} {
\begin{tikzpicture}
 ... MWE content above
\end{tikzpicture} }
If you post a solution based on your discovery, I will accept it when here next.